# How can I insert values from web browser Firefox or chrome like html and js to ethereum blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, blockchain, private-blockchain

How to save values from an HTML form into block chain through a browser, I have gone through different tutorials, but it is confusing, how this go-ethereum blockchain and smart contract can access from the browser. Please help me I am a noob with blockchain

Comment: See if https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/13/building-decentralized-apps-with-ethereum-and-javascript/ helps.

Comment: I don't even understand the question. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Have a look at web3.js

Comment: The Ethereum blockchain is not a data storage - or at least it's currently not feasible to store any bigger amounts of data there. Smart contracts are used to implement logic for small amounts of data. You should probably read more first about what the smart contract are and what they are meant for.

Comment: Did you use truffle framework.They have expalined all these stuff with metacoin.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen I know that it is not used for bigger amount of data. As a web developer i need to show the How the blockchain interact with ui. That is why i posted a question here, i have tried different tutorials, for achieving this, but still no luck

Comment: @CrissiMariamRobert Instead of using any metacoin, can i directly use blockchain with ui, as mysql is interacting with php?

Comment: @Naveenbos if you have further questions, please post a new Question in StackExchange. Comments are not meant for extended chat.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a smart contract that lets you pass in data in the form of a String or Int or whatever data type you are retrieving from the website.
2. Using html/css create the webpage and allow the user to input the data they want
3. retrieve the data the user submitted in the html with some backend like Node.js
4. use the [web3 api](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) to deploy your contract to the blockchain. For example:

   ```
   // deploy new contract
   var contractInstance = MyContract.new([data retrieved from html], {data: '0x12345...', from: myAccount, gas: 1000000});
   ```

**Note that it requires more steps to deploy a contract than just this snippet of code, just look online because there are many tutorials that literally walk you through the entire process.**

If you are new to programming, there are tutorials online for each of these steps. They just may not be all in 1 video.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with some good tutorials and examples.

Basically, you can communicate with ethereum node from website using a Javascript API called [Web3 JS](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API).

If you dont have a node already running, try private net.

1. [Download](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/) Geth
2. Create Genesis block -> Create accounts -> Start miner -> Enable JSON RPC HTTP communication for three modules (web3,eth,net), everything explained simply [HERE](https://medium.com/@solangegueiros/https-medium-com-solangegueiros-setting-up-ethereum-private-network-on-windows-a72ec59f2198).
3. Take a look at [Video demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jw6Vl7NYN3o) of Web3 JS.

Once you done with private nets, try test nets and main net.